# Cassandra cluster is not recovering after restarting?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I restarted my Cassandra cluster and now after its restarts, it shows that other nodes are unavailable. But when I check by going to those servers, it shows that Cassandra is running in those. Your help is highly appreciate.

nodetool repair - output

```
Repair session {session-id} for range (id] failed with error java.io.IOException: Cannot proceed on repair because a neighbor (/{ip}) is dead: session failed

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  {ip1}  2.06 GB    256     22.6%  {token 1}  1b
DN  {ip1}   ?          256     24.5%  {token 2}  1c
DN  {ip1}   ?          256     28.9%  {token 3}  1c
DN  {ip1}    ?          256     24.0%  {token 4}  1d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is you should alway restart one node at a time and wait for it to join the cluster (**UN**) before restarting others.

I am assuming all the nodes had previously joined the cluster and after a restart, they went out of sync. Do a rolling restart of all the nodes (one at a time) and wait for the node to join the cluster.

Cassandra prints and stores the communication and peers information in **system.peer** and **system.local** tables and they might go out of sync if you restart a node when another node is still in joining state.